# nfs directory is always mounted read only but /etc/fstab has rw options

Tags: amazon-ec2, nfs

I am trying to mount a nfs directory in rw mode but it is always getting mounted as read-only mode. In fact the uid and gid of the user who owns the directory is same as nfs server.

This is there in the /etc/fstab:

```
<nfs-server>:/home /home nfs rw,noatime,vers=3
```

Not sure what wrong I am doing here.

Strangely this happens when I use Jenkins EC2 plugin but works fine if I manully start an instance from an ami.  I checked the /etc/exports as well and it has no entry.
I even tried running `sudo mount -o remount,rw /home/` but I still end up with same error.